# Use options to toggle two sets of code

Tags: vba, excel

I have two option buttons on a user form. If you select one, it grays out and disables certain input boxes ind If you select the other, it restricts other input boxes and works great. So I have the appropriate code that executes what I want. HOWEVER, if the user makes a mistake and clicks one option and then tries to change their selection, the code has already executed and disabled those inputs. How do I get the code to toggle back and forth? Here is my code, thanks a lot for the help!

```
Sub Yes_Click()
If Yes.Value = True Then
    With Me.IncrementalImpactPricingInput1
    .Enabled = False
    .BackColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)
    End With

    With Me.IncrementalImpactFundingInput1
    .Enabled = False
    .BackColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)

    Me.BilledAmountInput1.Enabled = True

    End With
Else: Call No_Click

End If
End Sub

Sub No_Click()
If No.Value = True Then
    With Me.BilledAmountInput1
    .Enabled = False
    .BackColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)
    End With

Else: Call Yes_Click
    'With Me.IncrementalImpactPricingInput1
    '.Enabled = True
    '.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    'End With

    'With Me.IncrementalImpactFundingInput1
    '.Enabled = True
    '.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    'End With
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two option buttons as though they were two "round" checkboxes, forcing you to add code to keep them in sync with each other.
Instead, they should be contained within an Option Group, which takes care of the toggling automatically. Within the option group, assign the option buttons data values of 1 and 2. Then replace both your Click event handlers with:

```
Sub frameYesNo_AfterUpdate()
Select Case frameYesNo
    Case 1: ' "yes" stuff here
    Case 2: ' "no" stuff here
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Dont know if this is what you wanted)

'single click to lock

```
Private Sub No_Click()
With Me.BilledAmountInput1
.Enabled = False
.BackColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)
End With
End Sub
```

'double click to unlock

```
Private Sub No_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
With Me.BilledAmountInput1
.Enabled = True
.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End With
No.Value = False
End Sub
```

'single click to lock

```
Private Sub Yes_Click()
With Me.IncrementalImpactPricingInput1
.Enabled = False
.BackColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)
End With

With Me.IncrementalImpactFundingInput1
.Enabled = False
.BackColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)
End With
End Sub
```

'double click to unlock

```
Private Sub Yes_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
With Me.IncrementalImpactPricingInput1
.Enabled = True
.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End With

With Me.IncrementalImpactFundingInput1
.Enabled = True
.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End With
Yes.Value = False
End Sub
```